# Schedule for every afterRender for a View

Tags: ember.js, runloop

I would like to run code every time a view is rendered. The closest I can get is to listen to every property that could change and explicitly schedule something on the run loop for `afterRender`, but I would love to just have a lifecycle hook like `afterRender`. The property approach gets fragile, since you have to keep the list of properties up to date based on what can affect the render.

Controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  count: 0,
  actions: {
    add: function() {
      var count = this.get('count');
      count += 1;
      this.set('count', count);
    }
  }
});
```

View:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  changed: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this.after);
  }.observes('controller.count'),
  after: function() {
    console.log('after render', this.$('span').text());
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<button {{action "add"}}>add</button> <span>{{count}}</span>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wujogejeso/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

To schedule the code `afterRender`, you can use the `didInsertElement` lifecycle hook in place of your `changed` function.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this.after);
  },
  after: function() {
    console.log('after render', this.$('span').text());
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe this only schedules it once: after insertion. No subsequent run loops will execute the `after` method.